# Ubicar un input al costado derecho de una tabla

Tags: html, css

```css
.section-calendar{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.clima{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.calendario{
    background-color: bisque;
    width: 90%;
}

th{
    text-align: left;
}

table{
    width: 50%;
}

table input{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
table td{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-calendar">
        <div class="row calendar-row">
            <div class="col span-2-of-3 box calendario box">
              <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Dia</th>
                <th>Horario</th> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="diareservado">Aca van los dias reservados</td>
                <td id="hrreservado">Horario reservado</td> 
              </tr>
                  <input name="Fecha">
            </table>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-3 box clima">
                Aca vamos a meter data del clima.
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Hola! tengo un pequeño codigo, quiero colocar un input llamado "fecha"al lado de una tabla pero me esta quedando encima de ella.

Comment: Quieres que tu `input` quede alineado a la derecha con los datos de cada fila de la tabla ?

Comment: La estructura html que tienes es incorrecta, esto hace que el html no sea válido y que el resultado no sea el que esperas. Edita la pregunta para clarificar dónde quieres que vaya el input (añade una image si eso ayuda). También sería bueno que especificaras si se puede cambiar el html, el css, o ambos. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: 1. Tienes el `<input name="Fecha">` dentro de la tabla. Sácalo fuera. 2. Después en el css hay `table td{ float: left;}` Si realmente esto es lo que quieres, déjalo pero en este caso ya no tiene sentido utilizar una tabla. Yo borraría esta regla del css.